# Viewing your child's phone remotely, to supervise at will

Tags: remote-access, parental-control, google-family-link, teamviewer

I would like to know what the best app would be to supervise what a child is doing on a phone remotely (for instance, from another room, or from another viewing angle).

I am aware of TeamViewer, which, however, is not free, and requires permission to be entered (perhaps even reach time), to connect.

And there is Family Link (which comes in two apps, one for the parent's phone, and one for the child's phone, which allows the parent to monitor (even, by receiving notifications), what apps the child has installed.

But I am looking for something that lets me specify a one time premission that survives reboots on the child's phone, and bring up the child's screen on my screen at will.

How can I do this?

Thanks.